# Hide enemies in LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, hide, overlap

I am doing a super mario bross game and I want to make the carnivorous plants. My problem is that I don´t know how to hide the plant behind the pipes. I am using Tiled maps editor to make the map and I try to overlap the pipe layer over the plants layer but it doesn´t work. If you know a thread or something where it is explained it will be very helpfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the layers from within Tiled2D should also change the order in which they are rendered. (E.g. bottom layer rendered first, top layer rendered last).